# Duplicate records postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have my following sql query, the problem when I run it is that it shows me some duplicate records, I would appreciate if you can help me

```sql
SELECT a.codeps,
       b.deneps,
       a.codlocacion,
       c.denlocacion,
       concat(substring(a.fcontable, 7, 2), '-', substring(a.fcontable, 5, 2), '-', substring(a.fcontable, 1, 4)) AS fcontable,
       a.codcuenta,
       d.dencuenta,
       d.inf,
       a.glosa,
       (a.movdeudor-a.movacreedor) AS movimiento,
       e.inicial
FROM moveps04 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN eps AS b ON a.codeps=b.codeps
LEFT OUTER JOIN localidad AS c ON a.codeps=c.codeps
AND a.codlocacion=c.codlocacion
LEFT OUTER JOIN plancuentas AS d ON trim(a.codcuenta)=trim(d.cuenta)
LEFT OUTER JOIN saldoseps AS e ON a.codeps=e.codeps
AND trim(a.codcuenta)=trim(e.codcuenta)
WHERE a.codeps=4
  AND a.codlocacion=2
  AND a.periodo<='201603'
  AND substring(trim(a.periodo), 1, 4)='2016'
  AND substring(trim(a.codcuenta), 1, 3)='339'
  AND e.anio='2016'
ORDER BY a.codeps,
         a.codlocacion,
         a.codcuenta
```

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd9Ux.png)

Comment: You get duplicates by joining table `saldoseps`. Seems like that there is at least 1:n relationship between tables. If you need more support you need to enhance your question with data examples.